# How to send serializable request object with httpClient in .net core?

Tags: json, rest, asp.net-core, httpclient

I'm new in .net and I'm looking for a way (if exists) to be able to pass a request object to a http client without "manually" serialize it to json. I did some java implementations in the past and there it was done under the hood and I thought that it should be possible also in .netCore

This is the request object:

```
public class Request
{
    [JsonProperty("number", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm looking for something like:

```
var request = new Request {Number=2};
client.PostAsync("url", request)
```

I found a similar implementation, but that does not seems to be .netcore compatible:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.2.4-preview1

Is there anything similar for .netcore?

Thanks

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` targets .NET Standard. The naming is a little off because it was written for the original ASP.NET Web Api (instead of Core), but its 100% compatible with Core. All it does is add extensions to `HttpClient` which is not Web Api-specific.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to serialize the object to a JSON string.

The referenced `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` library in question would have the `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method along with many others for extending `HttpClient`.

Which internally may have looked like this.

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, T obj) {
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); 
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);    
}
```

and used like

```
using System.Net.Http;

//...

var request = new Request { Number = 2 };
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("url", request);
```

Comment: `PostAsJsonAsync` already exists in the framework, it's simply an extension that requires an additional using statement.

Comment: Actually this the answer I was looking for. Somehow I didn't find this `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method, but it is available indeed, and it does what I was looking for.  Thank you.